# Featured image and og meta not showing up in Facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook, og-meta

I'm having an issue with the thumbnail / featured image, headline and og meta not showing up if I paste a link in FB with one specific post but not others. (Flushing the cache on FB doesn't work).

The site's on WordPress and the Yoast SEO plug-in should sort out the OG meta tags if you correctly enter your FB settings in the right section and I believe I have. I have also just pasted the code in my theme's functions.php

Here is my most recent blog post where it has no image nor headline: http://robcubbon.com/essential-wordpress-plug-ins-website/ 
– however it works on other posts

On the Debug tool it says: Must: "The 'og:type' property is required, but not present". But it's there : `<meta property="og:type" content="article" />`

It also says: Should: "The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags." And it's there: 
`<meta property="og:url" content="link here" />`

The OG Meta is exactly the same on this post (as far as I can see) as all other posts that have featured image and other meta info displaying properly in FB.

I would really appreciate if someone know why this is happening

Comment: The provided link is dead but everything works for me with other links from your page. Please edit the question and add the solution if it's resolved.

Comment: The link was dead for only a few places due to a caching issue. My host deleted the residue of files left over by a deactivated caching plugin – this allowed everyone to see the link properly and, after entering the link in the FB debugging tool, the OG meta displayed properly in FB when the link was pasted in. So it was all to do with caching.